# A simple word for 'things we dont do'

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a simple word defining 'things we dont do'. Tell me as many words because I need to do an assignment. Please help me out.
Thank You.

Comment: Look in a thesaurus for prohibitions.

Comment: Also, *homework*.

Comment: Please see our [guidelines for asking homework questions](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/346/300). Specifically, "make a good-faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first" and "ask about *specific* problems with your *existing* approach to answering the question". And by the way, "a simple word" and "as many words as possible" is a contradiction. Are you looking for an adjective or a noun? A negative or a positive connotation? How do you define "simple" — most common? the shortest? the easiest to pronounce for a native speaker of Belorussian?

Comment: Since you said "simple", consider *no-no*.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I thought of:

**taboo**

*Oxford Dictionary of English*

> ► noun
>
> (pl. taboos or tabus) a social or religious custom prohibiting or restricting a particular practice or forbidding association with a particular person, place, or thing.
>
> ► adjective
>
> prohibited or restricted by social custom: sex was a taboo subject.
>
> ■ designated as sacred and prohibited: the burial ground was seen as a taboo place.

Oxfords thesaurus lists the following as synonyms for taboo as a noun:

> prohibition, proscription, veto, interdiction, interdict, ban, restriction, boycott, non-acceptance, anathema.

and the following as synonyms for taboo as an adjective:

> forbidden, prohibited, banned, proscribed, vetoed, ruled out, interdicted, outlawed, not permitted, not allowed, illegal, illicit, unlawful, impermissible, not acceptable, restricted, frowned on, beyond the pale, off limits, out of bounds;
>
> unmentionable, unspeakable, unutterable, ineffable, censored;
>
> rude, impolite, indecorous, dirty;
>
> German verboten;
>
> Islam haram;
>
> NZ tapu;
>
> informal **no go**;
>
> rare non licet.

Comment: Let the downvoting commence

Comment: perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

The most specific term I can think of is "***proscriptions***" (**note**: *pro-*, not *pre-*, we're not talking about medicine here).

> [***proscripton***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proscription) : *the act of proscribing; the state of being proscribed*
>
> [***proscribe***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proscribe) : *to make (something) illegal; to not allow (something)*

See also: ***injunctions***, ***prohibitions***, ***disallowances***, etc.

Comment: err .. another perfect answer!  :)